# Go Module Import - Invalid version: go.mod has malformed module path

Tags: go, go-modules

I have looked all over for an answer for "go.mod has malformed module path" but I have not found an answer to why I can't get a library I am writing to import. To simplify I have made a tiny library repo: https://github.com/buphmin/test-go-pkg

Note: I am using the stripe api library for structure inspiration. https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go

**Problem**:

I create a library, go mod init , push code and tag to github. Then try to import package to use the library elsewhere and I get an error message: 'go get: github.com/buphmin/test-go-pkg@v1.0.0: invalid version: go.mod has malformed module path "github.com/buphmin/test-go-pkg/v1" at revision v1.0.0'

I have no idea why this is an issue and I have not found an answer thus far.

**Steps to Reproduce**

Assuming you have go installed.

- Create local folder
- go mod init <your_mod>
- go get github.com/buphmin/test-go-pkg/v1
- error occurs

**Other info**

- go v1.16
- ubuntu 18 LTS

**go mod file**
Copied from the source of truth listed above: https://github.com/buphmin/test-go-pkg

```
module github.com/buphmin/test-go-pkg/v1

go 1.16
```

Edit - Answer:

My understand now with the help of @Steven Penny is that v1, v2, etc has more significance than just organization. This article explains how go treats that versioning https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/golang-go-package-management.

Comment: If you need help debugging your `go.mod`, it would be prudent to include the contents of that file in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
module github.com/buphmin/test-go-pkg/v1
```

is not valid. Should be this:

```
module github.com/buphmin/test-go-pkg
```

Comment: Hmm, how does it work here then? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/master/go.mod what am I missing?
```module github.com/stripe/stripe-go/v72```

Comment: @buphmin you dont have version `v72` you have version `1`. Anything less than `2`, you dont use the `v` syntax